# Can ArcGIS only merge two shapefiles each time?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, point, merge

I need to merge multiple point shapefiles (in the same directory) into one point shapefile. After inputting these shapefiles and merging it, I found the final output only contained the data from two shapefiles. How to merge multiple shapefile in ArcGIS at once instead of merging only two at each time?

Comment: What tool are you using to do the merge? You say you are merging "point shapefiles in the same database", what do you mean by "database"?

Comment: Only MERGE .................suitable flexible durable reproducible
Data Management-General

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like it might be more useful to use the '[Append](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000)' tool in the Data Management toolbox, that will let you specify multiple inputs to append to an existing feature class.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your input features must all be the same data type. Using the merge tool, you can input more than 2.

Or, just append the new data to an existing shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you all for your help! I just figured out that in my case, the failure is cause by different coordinate system those shapefiles are in. Once I make the coordinate system consistent, I was able to merge multiple files at once.